# Irreducible polynomial Mod $2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

would the polynomial $x^5+x^3+1$ Mod $2$ be irreducible?

I've tried factorizing, however, can't seem to find any factors? if it is irreducible how can i conclude this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easily checked that $f(x) = x^5 + x^3 + 1$ has no roots over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Therefore, if it *is* reducible, then the only remaining possibility is that it can be written as a product of an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible cubic in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

From here, it's pretty straightforward to list every irreducible quadratic and cubic in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and multiply every possible pair of them.  As a hint in listing these polynomials, keep in mind that a polynomial of degree $\leq 3$ is irreducible $\iff$ it has no roots.

**Even easier**: You'll discover that there is only one irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  To save time, you can instead perform polynomial long division to show that it is not a factor of $f$, and thus $f$ is irreducible.

**Bottom line**: There are only a finite number of possible quadratic/cubic factors of $f$ since we are working over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Eliminate all of them, and you can safely conclude that $f$ has no factors.

Comment: when you say there is only one irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ could you state which one?

Comment: is it $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: Indeed it is @smith.  The question for you to ponder is why is it the only one.

Comment: also when you states that a poly of def $ \leq 3$ is irreducible $\iff$ it has no roots is this for all modulo?

Comment: Yes: Suppose a polynomial $f$ is a cubic or quadratic and it is reducible.  Then we have $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $1 \leq \deg(g), \deg(h) < \deg(f)$.  So notice that at least one of the factors must be a linear factor, which is of the form $x-c$, and so $c$ is a root.

Comment: Oh, I should add that we typically only look at irreducibility of polynomials over integral domains, since multiplying two polynomials over an integral domain results in their degrees adding, and we don't get any weird stuff happening.  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain only when $n$ is prime, so you'll generally only be looking at these things mod $2, 3, 5$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to prove that $x^5+x^3+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ is to prove that $x^{32}-x$ is divisible by $x^5+x^3+1$ and that $x^5+x^3+1$ has no linear factors.

More generally, if $f(x)\in\mathbb Z_p[x]$ is of degree $q$, with $q$ prime, then $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if it is a factor of $x^{p^q}-x$ and it has no linear factors.

You have to switch to [cyclomatic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) if you want to deal with the case of $q$ not prime. Then, you need $\Phi_{p^q}(x)$ divisible by $f(x)$.

Comment: Gee, that's interesting!  ***Endorsed!!!***  Where (preferably online) might I find a discussion/proof of the result(s) you quoted?

Comment: Not sure what the best source of this is, online, but check out this section on the Wikipedia page for finite fields: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Polynomial_factorization

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.